# distance between vertices in triangle

Tags: geometry

Prove that the sum of distances from any point in the interior of a triangle to three vertices of the triangle is less than the sum of two larger sides of the triangle

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: We can't just help you if we don't know how much you've done.

Comment: I understand...I was away from the computer. Let me type in what I have.

Comment: I have this:  Given triangle ABC with point D in the interior then AD+BD+CD > (AB+BC+AC)/2.  Then from here, I'm going to say that AB and BC are the two largest sides.  But I don't exactly know where to go from here.  Still working on this.

Comment: @mepinon but the problem asks for an upper bound not a lower bound...

Comment: While its true that $a+b>l_a+l_b$, I have a hard time believing that $a+b>l_a+l_b+l_c$. I should play with Geo-Gebra to check if there's any counterexamples.

Comment: I'm still stuck on this problem...any ideas

Answer (score 1):

Let us prove that 
$$PA+PB+PC\lt AB+BC$$
always holds for any point $P$ inside $\triangle{ABC}$ satisfying $AB\ge BC\ge CA$.

**Proof** :

Consider an ellipse whose foci are $A,C$ that passes through $P$. Let $Q,R$ be the intersection point between the ellipse and the side $AB,BC$ respectively. Here, we have
$$PA+PC=QA+QC=RA+RC.$$

So, if $P$ is on the ellipse, we have that $PA+PC$ is constant and that $PB$ is max when $P$ is either on $Q$ or on $R$.

Hence, we have $(1)$ or $(2)$ :

$$PA+PB+PC\lt QA+QB+QC=AB+QC\tag1$$
$$PA+PB+PC\lt RA+RB+RC=BC+RA\tag2$$

For $(1)$, we have $QC\lt BC$ because
$$\angle{QBC}\le\angle{QAC}\lt\angle{QAC}+\angle{ACQ}=\angle{BQC}.$$

For $(2)$, we have $RA\lt AB$ because
$$\angle{ABR}\le\angle{ACR}\lt\angle{ACR}+\angle{RAC}=\angle{ARB}.\quad\blacksquare$$